# How to extract a date just before specific string in unstructured data?

Tags: r

I have unstructured text with many dates inside it, I would like to extract the date just before the word **"Message"**. The data I have look like this:

```
21 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
21 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
21 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
21 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text 
22 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
22 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
22 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
22 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text 
23 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
23 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
23 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
23 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text 
24 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
24 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
24 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
24 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text
```

and the output will be a new dataframe with one column for the date:

```
21 March 2017 
22 March 2017 
23 March 2017 
24 March 2017
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
sub("(?<=\\d{4}).*", "", grep("Message", txt, value=TRUE), perl=TRUE)
# [1] "21 March 2017" "22 March 2017" "23 March 2017" "24 March 2017"
```

First we use `grep()` to reduce `txt` to only the values containing "Message", then `sub()` to remove all the text after the first occurrence of a four-digit number.

Data:

```
txt <- readLines(textConnection("21 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
21 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
21 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
21 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text 
22 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
22 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
22 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
22 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text 
23 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
23 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
23 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
23 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text 
24 March 2017 23:10:45 text1
24 March 2017 23:10:45  More text…..
24 March 2017 23:10:45 And more text …..
24 March 2017 23:10:45 some more text **Message:** more text 
"))
```

Comment: I'll leave it to OP to put into a data frame.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!!